# Convergence and analytic continuation of a specific infinite product

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, infinite-product, analytic-continuation

I've been working on this for months, and I think it's time to give up and appeal to the internet for help.
$$\prod_{p}p^{\large 1/\left(\,1 -p^{s}\,\right)}$$ 
When does this converge and how can I get a continuation of it over all
$s\in \mathbb{C}$. ( $p$ means over the primes ).

Don't be afraid to get too technical on me. Some of complex analysis is a bit beyond me, but if it leads to an answer to my problem, I'll learn any bit of it that you think could help me. Really, any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Clearly if $p^s\to0$, then the product diverges to $+\infty$.  If $p^s\to1^+$, then the product diverges to $0$.

Comment: Also, have you tried taking the log of the product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given product equals
$$ \exp\left(-\sum_p \frac{\log p}{p^s-1}\right)\tag{1}$$
that is absolutely convergent for any $s:\text{Re}(s)>1$. On the same region Euler's product
$$ \zeta(s)=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1} \tag{2} $$
leads to
$$ \frac{d}{ds}\log\zeta(s) = \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = -\sum_{p}\frac{\log p}{p^s-1}\tag{3} $$
and to:
$$ \prod_p  p^{\frac{1}{p^s-1}}=\exp\left(\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\right)=\exp\left(-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}\right)\tag{4} $$
where $\Lambda(n)$ is [Von Mangoldt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function) function.The analytic continuation to the complex plane can be derived from the analytic continuation for the $\zeta$ function.

Comment: Darn, I'm a few seconds too late :D

Comment: Wait, does this mean that it's also a dirichlet series, or at least a general dirichlet series given that it converges on a half plane?  Or am I making a "all cats are animals, but all animals aren't cats" type error?

Comment: @Prince_Tat: the exponential of a Dirichlet series.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yeah, I've just realized that you also answered my question before I even asked it in (4).

Comment: @Prince_Tat Yes $\exp(F(s))$ is a Dirichlet series when $F(s)$ is. In general if $h$ is analytic on $U$ then $h(F(s))$ is a Dirichlet series iff $F(\infty) \in U$